# new.target with a prefix operator

Tags: javascript, safari, ecmascript-6, webkit

"The new.target property lets you detect whether a function or constructor was called using the new operator" [[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target)

I can use `new.target` in an if statement to throw an error if a function was not called using `new`:

```
if(!new.target){
    throw new Error('Must be called with new keyword!')
}
```

However, safari prevents `new.target` from being used with the `!` in this way, with the error message

> new.target can't come after a prefix operator

I tracked this down to [this line in Webkit](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/cfccd2a389b08c585095f58b2cd400c1fe5f0042/Source/JavaScriptCore/parser/Parser.cpp#L4887).

However the positive condition can be checked!

```
if(new.target){}
else{
    throw new Error('Must be called with new keyword!')
}
```

Is this an error with safari's parsing engine? Or alternatively, *should* I be using `new.target` in the way they enforce?

simple repro: https://codepen.io/mdjasper/pen/eEWORY?editors=0012

---

Edit: This issue has been filed on webkit bugzilla: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157970

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you say `!(new.target)`?

Comment: Great question, didn't think of that. Just tried it out, and still errors out though :/

Comment: Man, that is so strange. [Browser compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) shows it has full support in Safari, but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) says no support...

Comment: It definitely looks like a bug. I guess it's supposed to be `new.target === undefined` since it's exactly the thing you're checking, isn't it?

Comment: Absolutely a Safari bug, please file it if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax should be supported, and the error was confirmed to be a webkit bug:

```
if(!new.target){
    throw new Error('Must be called with new keyword!')
}
```

A patch has been written and merged, and will ship with a future version of webkit

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157970#c17

Until the fix lands in a released version, a workaround is to explicitly check `new.target`

```
if(new.target === undefined){
    throw new Error('Must be called with new keyword!')
}
```